# Convert geojson to dataframe in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, geometry, geojson

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[{u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [[[u'23.514690935490876',
      u'53.946715071429367'],
     [u'23.512760416665913', u'53.951647949218227'],
     [u'23.504458179704329', u'53.948463039349463'],
     [u'23.504036155000108', u'53.947045080000237'],
     [u'23.514690935490876', u'53.946715071429367']]],
   u'type': u'Polygon'},
  u'id': u'1',
  u'properties': {u'Id': u'1989436',
  u'OBJECTID': u'1',
  u'Shape_Area': u'3.117488307172805e-05',
  u'Shape_Length': u'0.026328682437290335',
  u'gridcode': u'2'},
  u'type': u'Feature'},
{u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [[[u'23.549827385369554',
    u'53.942282407709513'],
    [u'23.547151692707644', u'53.951826985676632'],
    [u'23.53984374999925', u'53.944519042968238'],
    [u'23.544863781644892', u'53.943109170298612'],
    [u'23.549827385369554', u'53.942282407709513']]],
   u'type': u'Polygon'},
   u'id': u'2',
   u'properties': {u'Id': u'1989437',
   u'OBJECTID': u'2',
   u'Shape_Area': u'4.6076356255779675e-05',
   u'Shape_Length': u'0.030493766995691507',
   u'gridcode': u'5'},
   u'type': u'Feature'},
   ...
```

I am trying to create a dataframe. I tried using this:

```
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

 df_norm = json_normalize(json_data["geometry"])
```

But I get an error that this is a string:

```
 "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I can convert it to the other format, but what would be the right type and the right approach?

Thanks!